# Click event doesn't fire on Android 4.1 on dojo.mobile

Tags: android, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

This is a continuous discussion from Worklight Forum. -> 
"[Click event doesn't fire on Android 4.1](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14939570&#14939570) "

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I reopened this Dojo ticket to track the problem: http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/15878

It seems, from other users who reported the same thing, that the problem occurs when you use the Chrome browser, but not when you use the "standard" Android browser. Can you confirm this?

Comment: My Galaxy Note II has two icons for browser as 'Browser' and 'Chrome'.

On 'Browser', Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.1; ja-jp; SC-02E Build/JRO03C) AppleWebKit/534.30(KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30)
Click event doesn't fire on both dojo.connect for RoundRect or &lt;div onclick=".."&gt;

On 'Chrome', Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.1; ja-jp; SC-02E Build/JRO03C) AppleWebKit/535.19(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19
Click event doesn't fire on dojo.connect for RoundRect but sometimes works on &lt;div onclick=".."&gt;

Comment: OK, thanks. We do see some problem on Chrome Mobile, but this browser is not officially supported. But since you see problems also with the Android browser we will do our best to investigate and test on Galaxy Note 2.